# How to open Outbox/Sent-Emails in default email client, from Javascript on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, outlook, mailto, thunderbird

On the click of a button, I want to show the user what emails have been sent (by another program/module which does automatic email based reporting when certain criteria are met) by my program while he was away.

So I have thought that a good way would be that, on button click, the default email client (e.g. thunderbird email client) of the user is opened, and  it is opened at "Outbox/ Sent Emails" rather than the default "inbox/ incoming email"?

How can I implement this functionality? That is what technology/plugin/library/Utility to use?

When I did Google search, it only showed results for wanting to open email client at "Compose Message/ Email" page, using the **`mailto`** utility in Javascript. But I need to open the email client at Outbox/Outgoing/Sent Email.

Comment: This is not possible. All you can do from the browser is tell the host machine to open an email editor in the default client. You cannot open that default client, nor tell it which folder to show.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to automate Outlook from JS code to display any sent message or folder. Only Internet Explorer knows how to deal with COM servers, see [Compose and Send E-mail from JavaScript by using Outlook Automation 2007](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rajnishkaushik/2007/05/06/compose-and-send-e-mail-from-javascript-by-using-outlook-automation-2007/).